# How can I restrict styling a closed Shadow DOM to particular outer hosts?

Tags: css, shadow-dom, native-web-component

I'd like to style an inner custom element's closed Shadow DOM from an outer custom element. – Outside the *outer* custom element, the inner Shadow DOM should not be stylable.

So, in general, a particular parent element is supposed to style its children, but outside the parent element, nothing should be able to style these children.

How would I do that?

AFAIK, the `part` attribute cannot be restricted to particular hosts or a maximum nesting level.

### Example

Imagine a custom element `night-sky` that's supposed to contain hundreds of `star-item` custom elements:

```html
<night-sky>
  <star-item/>
  <star-item/>
  <star-item/>
  <star-item/>
  ...
</night-sky>
```

The `<night-sky>` custom element's definition is supposed to set each `<star-item>` custom element's common CSS rules, e.g.: `position: absolute; width: 8px; height: 8px; background-image: url(star.png);`

I don't want to apply these common CSS rules to each single `<star-item>` custom element itself as it would add an undesired burdon to the browser. So, I want the `<night-sky>` custom element to set the common CSS rules once for all its children. However, outside the `<night-sky>` custom element I don't want anything to be able to alter the `<star-item>` custom elements' style.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your logic.

Make `<star-item>` read its **common styles** from a definition inside `<night-sky>`

But you **can't block** *inheritable styles*
Only block Specificity with `!important` (or add more wrapping Element Nodes and styles)

A *closed* shadowRoot is only about script access through (no longer available) `this.shadowRoot`

Minor note: `::slotted` targets Element Nodes, not Text Nodes (see FOO)

```js
customElements.define("star-item",class extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super();
    (this.root = this.attachShadow({mode:"closed"}))
     .innerHTML = `<style>
                     :host { color: beige!important }
                   </style>
                   <style id="common"></style>
                   <b part="title">Web Component</b> <slot></slot><br>`;
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    let sky = this.closest("night-sky");
    let html = sky.querySelector("template[id='star-item']").innerHTML;
    this.root.querySelector("style[id='common']").innerHTML = html;
  }
})
```

```css
star-item{ font:21px arial;background:lightcoral;color:white} /* inheritable styles */

star-item::part(title){ /* parts do style closed shadowRoots */
  font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<night-sky>
  <template id="star-item">
      :host(.active){ background:lightgreen!important; color:black!important } 
      ::slotted(*){ background:green;color:gold }
  </template>
  <star-item>FOO</star-item>
  <star-item><span>BAR</span></star-item>
  <star-item class="active"><b>BAZ</b></star-item>
</night-sky>
```

Comment: Great idea! Thank you for sharing it with me! — PS: W3C docs claim that `Element::shadowRoot` still exists and that styles from the "outside world" won't be applied to closed shadow DOMs: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-shadow-parts-1/

Comment: Yes, the shadowRoot still exists, there just is not a ``this.shadowRoot`` reference. Also note (see example) ``::part`` still work for ``closed`` shadowRoots

Comment: Today I had a chance to reproduce the solution you provided. Actually, with your suggestion, still each `<star-item>` elements comes with the same set styles. So, if I add 100 `<star-item>` elements, I will end up with 100 `<style>` elements. That's what I actually wanted to avoid. – That's what my question was about: "Is there a selector on a parent element that I can use to apply styles to child elements with closed Shadow DOM?" … appartently, the short answer seems to be: "no".

Comment: I read you question you wanted to "lock" a Web Component to one style and prevent styling from global styles. What you now write sounds like you want https://web.dev/constructable-stylesheets/

Comment: A lot of links from that old Google post are broken.  Apple finally  implemented this a month ago (Safari 16.4 - march 29, 2023) Constructable Stylesheet are now supported in all evergreen browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptedStyleSheets

Comment: Great suggestion! That's making things clear. And, as far as I understand the article, applying an adopted style sheet does not duplicate code and, thus, add burdon to the browser then? So it's leaner than applying a style sheet to all `<star-item>` elements?

Comment: But now you have have Web Components "watching" a shared stylesheet... Sounds to me you fear something more than actually experiencing performance issues?